# Python - Creating a command line like interface for loading modules/functions

Tags: python, command-line, interface, module

In my Python project I'm trying to make the interface somewhat like a command prompt where I can type the name of a function and it will be executed.
Example:

```
Prompt >>> run.check
Running function check....
Prompt >>> run.get
Running function get
```

In the above example when I type run.check it should run a function named check and run.get should run function get and so on.

Right now I have a prompt using raw_input and I can execute commands by using a dictionary of function alias' and function names ie,

```
COMMANDS = {'exit': sys.exit,
 'hello': greet,
 'option3': function3,
 'option4': function4,
}
cmd = raw_input("Prompt >>> ")

COMMANDS.get(cmd, invalidFunction)()
```

But a lot of the functions in my programs needs arguments to be passed to it which I do not know how to do with this method.
Another thing is that, the main purpose of my project is for modules (.py files) to be added to a folder and then executed dynamically with the main python program using the command prompt like interface and I would like to do this with minimum if possible no change to the main program.

I'm not sure of using the function exec as it has some drawbacks concerning security.

Thank You.

Comment: Are the arguments literals?

Comment: "drawbacks concerning security." - So do a lot of things, could be a chance to practice implementing _idiot-proof_ solutions?

Comment: @JanneKarila No not always.

Comment: @TheMerovingian I see your point but exec allows users to execute their own code which would be, well, unproductive most of the time as there is no way for that code to be checked by developers. While the modules which are added can be checked (sanitized, if necessary) beforehand.

Comment: @GrimReaper: Sure. But, for arguments sake, lets say you have to write a module for each piece of code you want to run (say `X` modules). Wouldn't it be the same amount of work to write `X` checks to only allow those specific `X` functions to be processed using `exec`.

Comment: @TheMerovingian But in my program that would mean editing the main program which I would like to avoid, if possible.

Comment: @GrimReaper: Fair enough, I just like making people think about their decisions :P

Comment: @TheMerovingian Of course :) It did actually make me think twice about using exec.

Comment: Have you looked into [the `cmd` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html)?

Comment: @JanneKarila I'm looking into it now. But it does seem to solve the problem of dynamically loading modules though. Thanks Anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions. one with `exec` and one with `eval`. You can use them as a basis to implement your own:

1. This is a rough solution using exec to execute the commands and dynamically load the modules:

   ```
   >>> class MyDict(dict):
       def __getitem__(self, name):
           # overwrite __getitem__ for access of unknown variables
           print 'name in self:', name in self
           if not name in self:
               # TODO: handle ImportError
               module = __import__(name)
               return module
           return dict.__getitem__(self, name)


   >>> d = MyDict(x = 1)
   >>> exec 'print x' in d
   name in self: True
   1
   >>> exec 'print os' in d # this loads the os module because the variable os is not defined
   name in self: False
   <module 'os' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.pyc'>
   ```
2. If you do not want to use exec:

   ```
   >>> def exec_in_module(string):
       module, command = string.split('.', 1)
       module = __import__(module)
       try:
           return eval(command, module.__dict__)
       except SyntaxError:
           exec command in module.__dict__
           return None


   >>> exec_in_module('os.listdir(".")')
   ['README.md', ...]
   ```

Comment: Thanks. It's the closest thing to what I'm looking for.